# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1(Firebase)

Tags: firebase, linker, clang

I am getting the error below in an iOS (objective C) app of mine, after adding the pods for Firebase.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

One more piece of information which may be useful is a message I got in the terminal when executing the pod install command:

```
....... [!] The `myapp [Debug]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build
    setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myapp/Pods-myapp.debug.xcconfig'. 
    This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `myapp [Release]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build
    setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myapp/Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig'. 
    This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Seing this I tried to change the `Library Search Paths`, but with no success.
And for the "Remove the build settings from the target", what does it exactly mean? How can I do that?

I have already browsed the net and found a couple of post related to this error message, but I did not found anything useful to solve my problem.
The suggestions I found all failed. Any relevant tip would be more than welcome.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes, it is already a while ago. I don't quite remember the details for this particular one. But I can tell you the two lessons I learned from the few similar experiences I've had. First, if you have set libraries by hand before and are now switching to Pods, there may be some conflicts, so try to get rid of the library search path you may have set previously. Second, if you have spent already enough time and are starting to get a headache with all that. Go and build a brand new project, where you set the pods you need from start and then get the files you need from your previous project.

Comment: I have done this at least two times, and that was a good and rather fast solution. Good luck! I hope that helps.

Comment: lol, thanks . But i've faced the same crash both cocoapods and manual linking.